# Why require not accepting variable as path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, require

I assigned file path to a variable and tried to pass it to require function but it's not accepting it!

If require not accepting variable as parameter then how I'll give it?

[Click to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5fZH.jpg)

Comment: check props width/height and image path.you have any warning in your console ? or check direct link instead of variable with require if its working then change as further

Comment: can you provide more details and context about the error?

Comment: Why "click to see code"? Paste your code in and format it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try importing the image like so:

```
import iconPath from './united-kingdom.png';
```

and then you can use it like this:

```
 source={iconPath}
```